# Example of Artinian ring which is not a finitely generated k-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In wikipedia it says:

Let $A$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unity. Let $k$ be a field and $A$ finitely generated $k$-algebra. Then $A$ is Artinian if and only if $A$ is finitely generated as $k$-module.

Can anybody give me an example of Artinian ring which is a $k$-algebra but not finitely generated?

Comment: I want an example that the Artinian ring is a $k$-algebra but infinitely generated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real numbers over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, Artinian, but certainly not finitely generated.

Comment: Thank you for the example, could you briefly explain why it's Artinian?

Comment: Artinian means it satisfies the descending chain condition on ideals. What are the ideals in the real numbers?

Comment: Oh, I understand, those ideals are zero ideals hence satisfies the dcc